# How to get max field value length for each TEXT field in all tables in database

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I am trying to get information about the data in my database.  I have several columns in several tables that or type 'TEXT'.  I want to perform a query that will create a result that looks like:

```
|table_name|column_name|max_length|
-----------------------------------
|my_table  |name       |35        |
```

I have the query to get all the tables and columns:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND data_type = 'text'
ORDER BY table_name
```

But I can't figure out how to now go through each of those tables and columns to get the max length of each column.  I do have the query to get the max length of a specific column and table using:

```
SELECT 'my_table', 'name', MAX(LENGTH(name)) FROM my_table
```

How can I make a query that will get the max length dynamically based on the results of the query to get all tables and columns?

Comment: Do you care if the result is table_name|column_name|jsonb, where jsonb is `[{column_name: max_length}]`

Comment: @EvanCarroll I think that could work.

Comment: As this was a one off where I just needed some information about my data, I decided to go the manual but simple approach.  I took the results from my query for all the tables and columns and used a text editor to create a SELECT statement to get the max length for each column and UNIONed them all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for PL/pgSQL.

You can use a variation of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225/330315) to do everything in a single query.

```
select table_schema, 
       table_name,
       column_name, 
       (xpath('/row/max/text()',query_to_xml(format('select max(length(%I)) from %I.%I', column_name, table_schema, table_name), true, true, '')))[1]::text::int as max_length
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public'       
  and data_type = 'text'
order by table_schema, table_name, column_name;
```

---

Evan's comment got me thinking if there is a way to do this with a single statement per table (although I doubt that this performance optimization is really important for a "get me some information about my database query")

With a bit of XML juggling, it is indeed possible:

```
with counts as (
  select table_schema, 
         table_name,
         query_to_xml(format('select %s from %I.%I', string_agg(format('max(length(%I)) as %I', column_name, column_name), ', '), table_schema, table_name), 
                      true, true, '') as result
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'public'       
    and data_type = 'text'
  group by table_schema, table_name
)
select table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       substring(x::text, 2, strpos(x::text,'>') - 2) as column_name,
       (xpath('./text()', x))[1]::text::int as max_length
from counts, unnest(xpath('//row/*', result)) as c(x);
```

For the pagila demo database this returns:

```
table_schema | table_name                 | column_name | max_length
-------------+----------------------------+-------------+-----------
public       | actor_info                 | film_info   |        830
public       | customer_list              | notes       |          6
public       | customer_list              | name        |         21
public       | film                       | description |        130
public       | film_list                  | actors      |        216
public       | film_list                  | description |        130
public       | nicer_but_slower_film_list | actors      |        201
public       | nicer_but_slower_film_list | description |        130
public       | sales_by_store             | manager     |         12
public       | sales_by_store             | store       |         19
public       | staff_list                 | name        |         12
```

The above first generates one statement per table containing one `max(length(..))` for each column.

The result is then parsed and turned into rows again. It would be possible to aggregate that back into a single JSON.

---

To get one row per table, with the column information as a JSON value, the following can be used:

```
with counts as (
  select table_schema, 
         table_name,
         query_to_xml(format('select to_jsonb(t) as cols from (select %s from %I.%I) t', string_agg(format('max(length(%I)) as %I', column_name, column_name), ', '), table_schema, table_name), 
                      false, true, '') as result
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'public'       
    and data_type = 'text'
  group by table_schema, table_name
)
select table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       (xpath('//row/cols/text()', result))[1]::text::jsonb as column_sizes
from counts;
```

For the pagila demo database this returns:

```
table_schema | table_name                 | column_sizes                       
-------------+----------------------------+------------------------------------
public       | actor_info                 | {"film_info": 830}                 
public       | customer_list              | {"name": 21, "notes": 6}           
public       | film                       | {"description": 130}               
public       | film_list                  | {"actors": 216, "description": 130}
public       | nicer_but_slower_film_list | {"actors": 201, "description": 130}
public       | sales_by_store             | {"store": 19, "manager": 12}       
public       | staff_list                 | {"name": 12}
```

Comment: @EvanCarroll: of course it will take into account multiple columns of the same table. Why do you think it won't?

Comment: erg, I should have been cleaerer. Each additional text column will require a full table scan.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: yes, because that's the only way to do it. Otherwise you would wind up with a result that has a different number of columns per row which isn't possible.

Comment: Yep, or use JSONB or something https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/215826/2639

Answer (score 0):

This will return a series of select statements that will only query each table once returning the maximum length for every text column,

```
SELECT FORMAT(
        'SELECT %L AS table_catalog, %L AS table_schema, %L AS table_name, %s FROM %I.%I.%I;',
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name,
        string_agg(
                FORMAT('max(length(%I)) AS %I', column_name, column_name),
                ', '
                ORDER BY column_name
        ),
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'text'
GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
ORDER BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name;
```

Because the table can have different amount of text-columns, your only method of moving forward from that point is to use JSONB or some other schemaless type.

```
SELECT FORMAT(                                                                                                                                                           'SELECT %L AS table_catalog, %L AS table_schema, %L AS table_name, %s FROM %I.%I.%I;',
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name,
        string_agg(
                FORMAT( 'jsonb_build_object(%L,max(length(%I)))', column_name, column_name),
                ' || '
                ORDER BY column_name
        ),
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE data_type = 'text'
GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
ORDER BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name;
```

From this point you can just `UNION` them all together.

```
SELECT FORMAT( '%s;', string_agg(stmt, E'\nUNION ALL ') )
FROM (
  SELECT FORMAT(
    'SELECT %L AS table_catalog, %L AS table_schema, %L AS table_name, %s FROM %I.%I.%I',
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    string_agg(
      FORMAT( 'jsonb_build_object(%L,max(length(%I)))', column_name, column_name),
      ' || '
      ORDER BY column_name
    ),
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name
  )
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE data_type = 'text'
    AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog'
  GROUP BY table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
) AS t(stmt);
```

Running **the result** of that query (type `\gexec` if using psql) and your output should be something like,

```
 test          | master       | entities                  | {"entity_name": 6}
 test          | public       | geography_columns         | {"type": null}
 test          | public       | ip2loc_asn                | {"name": 29}
 test          | public       | t                         | {"event": 3}
 test          | public       | txns_combined             | {"item": 6, "to_party": 5, "from_party": 4}
 test          | tec          | codes_office              | {"office_id": 22, "office_name": 44}
 test          | tec          | codes_reports             | {"report_id": 15, "report_name": 70}
 test          | tec          | codes_texas_counties      | {"county_id": 3, "county_name": 13}
 test          | tec          | codes_total               | {"total_id": 22, "total_description": 112}
 test          | tec          | expendcategory            | {"recordtype": 5, "expendcategorycodelabel": 74, "expendcategorycodevalue": 10}
```